# Dark Souls 3: Special ability / parry (L2 on ps4) sometimes triggers unintentionally. Why?

Tags: dark-souls-3

On a Dark Souls 3 for ps4 (latest patch but it's always happened), if you're locked onto an enemy, sometimes hitting circle (to roll) causes your character to parry rather than roll if a shield is equipped.

This happens for all of the weapons I've used but it's not exclusively a parry thing- whatever your L2 trigger does (default control layout- it's the Parry button), sometimes will trigger randomly in fights. Sometimes not even in fights.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it? Has anyone else experienced this?

It's infuriating.

Edit:
I've further refined this to a specific, easily reproducible example.
If you equip the Deep Battle Axe, pressing up and circle at the same time will cause the action of L2 happen.

https://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls3/comments/4k063z/not_hitting_l2_but_powering_upparrying_somehow/

Edit 2:
Ok this just happens when you press L3.
Still. How do you turn it off?

Comment: Have tried noticing if you press L2 by mistake when pressing L3? Have you tried using a different controller to see if there's anything wrong with your DS4?

Comment: definitely happens on my white controller; i'll play for a while on my black one, but im pretty sure it happens on both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller was messed up for some reason.